# Second Time can not get input from user for String input

Tags: java

Below is the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculate{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int age=0;
    String name="";
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter value of your age : ");
    age=scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter value of your name : ");
    name=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Age : "+age+", Name : "+name);
  }
}
```

Now, Here the issue is taking String value from the user.

I can take two `INTEGER` values from user one by one after pressing `[ENTER]`. 
But, In case of taking `STRING` value from the user Second time, It just let me out after I enter value for Age variable.

If I first take the input for `String` and then `INTERGER` than it working fine as below : (First name and then age) :

```
    System.out.println("Please Enter value of your name : ");
    name=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please Enter value of your age : ");
    age=scan.nextInt();
```

What might be the issue ?

Comment: how are you providing the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `scan.nextInt()` method. It only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with `scan.nextLine()` you receive the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the `input.nextLine()`

**Try this:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int age=0;
    String name="";
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter value of your age : ");
    age=scan.nextInt();

    scan.nextLine(); // This line you have to add (It consumes the \n character)


    System.out.println("Please Enter value of your name : ");
    name=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Age : "+age+", Name : "+name);
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Please Enter value of your age :
20
Please Enter value of your name :
ABC
Age : 20, Name : ABC
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs as you hit the enter key, which is a newline `\n` character.

to add an additional `scan.nextLine()` after you read the int

```
System.out.println("Please Enter value of your age : ");
age=scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();// additional  line
```

Comment: So, Why it's working in case of Integer (If I take second integer value from user) ?

Comment: Integer dose not take `\n`